# Relationship between eigenvalues of two related, Euclidean distance matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}$ is a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then one can generate a Euclidean distance matrix $D = [d_{ij}]$ where $d_{ij}=\Vert x_i-x_j\Vert_2^2$ is the square of the Euclidean distance from point $i$ to point $j$.  Note that $X$ is real and symmetric (all real eigenvalues).

Suppose that I remove an element from $X$ to create $X^{\prime}$.  The corresponding matrix $D^{\prime}$ is related to $D$.  It is formed from $D$ by deleting the row and column corresponding to the element removed from $X$.

My question is: is there any relationship between the (non-zero) eigenvalues of $D$ and the non-zero eigenvalues of $D^{\prime}$?  Certainly, counting up multiplicities, $D^{\prime}$ has one fewer eigenvalue.  It is also known that any such Euclidean Distance Matrix has (at most) $n+2$ non-zero eigenvalues; it has exactly $n+2$ non-zero eigenvalues whenever $N>n$ and all the points in $X$ do not lie in some $N-1$ dimensional subspace.

EDIT: If it matters, in the case that I'm looking at, $n=3$ and $N$ is much bigger (on the order of 100s).

Comment: Maybe you can use that fact that if M is Hermitian, you can write D = N^{-1}MN, where M and N are orthogonal, and D is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal (I haven't actually worked out anything, it just looks like a promising direction to look).

Comment: Google Cauchy interlacing theorem.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks, I will do that.